# Identify filesystem for each mtd

Tags: filesystems, proc

In `/proc/mtd` I can see all partition in my device

```
dev:    size   erasesize  name
mtd0: 0xxxxx00 0xxxxx00 "yyyy"
mtd1: 0xxxxx00 0xxxxx00 "yyyy"
mtd2: 0xxxxx00 0xxxxx00 "yyyy"
```

How can I know which file system is each mtd? ntfs?jffs2?ramfs?